# difference between with/without typeof in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the difference between with/without `typeof` before interface?

Does it change the behavior? I couldn't find the doc for this.

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
type Item = React.FC<Props>;
type Component = React.FC & {
  Item: typeof Item;
}
```

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
type Item = React.FC<Props>;
type Component = React.FC & {
  Item: Item;
}
```

Comment: `typeof` is used to extract the type of a value, or as a special case, to extract the constructor type of a class. In this example, there should be an error on your first snippet: `Item only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`, indicating that using `typeof` in that spot is not valid.

Comment: [Docs for the `typeof` operator can be found here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html)

Comment: Keep in mind that the `typeof` _type operator_ is a typescript feature and is distinct from the [built-in javascript `typeof` _value operator_, which can be read about here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: The difference is that one compiles and not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one doesn't make sense because `typeof` can only be applied to values, not to types.